# How does yields know where to grab the correct html snippet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

I started messing around with ruby and I have very little web developing experience. I am trying to understand how ruby code injection works with with yield snippets. I been hacking away google's example book code

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-ruby/blob/master/5-logging/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

I am currently looking at this code snippet in the main view/layout/ directory

```
<div class="container">
  <% if flash.any? %>
    <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= type %>"><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

I am stuck figuring out how yield links to /view/books/index.html.erb

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-ruby/blob/master/5-logging/app/views/books/index.html.erb

```
     <h3>Books</h3>

    <%= link_to new_book_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>Add Book</span>
    <% end %>

    <% @books.each do |book| %>
      <div class="book media">
        <%= link_to book_path(book) do %>
          <div class="media-left">
            <img src="<%= book.image_url %>">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4><%= book.title %></h4>
            <p><%= book.author %></p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "pagination_link" %>

    <% if @books.none? %>
      <p>No books found.</p>
    <% end %>
```

Here is a rake routes so you dont have to run it

```
           rake routes
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
                  books GET    /books(.:format)                       books#index
                        POST   /books(.:format)                       books#create
               new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)                   books#new
              edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)              books#edit
                   book GET    /books/:id(.:format)                   books#show
                        PATCH  /books/:id(.:format)                   books#update
                        PUT    /books/:id(.:format)                   books#update
                        DELETE /books/:id(.:format)                   books#destroy
                       login GET    /login(.:format)                  redirect(301, /auth/google_oauth2) auth_google_oauth2_callback GET    /auth/google_oauth2/callback(.:format) sessions#create
               session POST   /session(.:format)                     sessions#create
                        DELETE /session(.:format)                     sessions#destroy
                user_books GET    /user_books(.:format)                  user_books#index
                 logout GET    /logout(.:format)                      sessions#destroy
                   root GET    /                                      books#index
```

Comment: Have you already studied [Understanding yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield)?

Comment: I tried reading that link already. I am still confused. Everything seems so implicit. It is really difficult to find searchable keywords to understand the code

Comment: This might also help: [`ActionView::Layouts`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html)

Answer (score 2):

`yield` is part of Ruby's [`block syntax`](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html).

```
def hello
  "Hello, #{yield}!"
end

> hello { "World" }
# => "Hello, World!"
```

In this example, the `hello` method yields to the block we pass in to get a value, and adds it to the string.

Think of templates as being a special kind of file for creating functions that generate html. Layouts and partials are ways of embedding templates inside one another, just like you can call a function from within another function.

Your templates are rendered by the Controller, so it knows what view needs to be rendered, and what layout it belongs to according to the [Rails conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).

Comment: Yea, I understand that yield receives a value. My problem is understanding is how it knows which controller to render the yield block. I already took a look at both the application and image controller

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-ruby/blob/master/5-logging/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-ruby/blob/master/5-logging/app/controllers/books_controller.rb

I still cannot find the line that specifies anything

Comment: The `yield` keyword is not doing the work here, it is simply telling Ruby to yield execution to another piece of code. The Controller is the thing doing the execution in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't try to find the view. It just passes the control to the controller, so that the controller can decide which view to render.

Comment: So where does the application passed the control to the controller?

The problem with ruby on rails that everything is so implicit that I cannot even read tutorials because the framework is doing black magic everywhere. All the links provided does not really explain the lack of code above

Comment: @user1462442 The Rails router is what matches URLs to controllers/actions and dispatches accordingly. After that this Rails guide should explain everything you need: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#overview-how-the-pieces-fit-together

So the whole process kinda goes like this (simplified): request hits app server - the Rails router matches the request URL to a controller action - the action performs its work and renders a response. The exact location of views etc. can be inferred due to Rails "convention over configuration" approach.

Comment: @Michael Kohl base on your comment. Since root is specified as book#index.

When the user calls, rails maps that call to htts:://bookself.com/ -> book#index -> BookContoller -> render book.erb -> "yield" (application.erb)

Comment: @user1462442 Basically. I hope that helped a bit in understanding what's going on.